# high CPU usage and drop in data transfer from site to HQ

Tags: cisco, vlan, ipv4, mac-address

In the next topology I face a problem in CPU usage and data transfer from site to HQ 
[image]
During the handheld data transfer from one site to server in HQ ,CPU usage in all site switches (SW1,SW2,SW3) increased and after while handhelds couldn't be discovered by its agent in HQ and its data stopped  to be transferred.here a copy of output of command ***sh proce cpu sorted** 
[image]

after alot of ***clear arp*** , ***clear mac address-table dynamic*** no thing could happen .also handhelds still not working till I reload all switches .

***NOTES***

- I run RSTP on all switches
- I run router on stick method for the data and voice vlan so the router is the GW for both
- Router is 2901 , switches are 2960
- handhelds are assigned DATA VLAN IPs and GW

Answer (score 2, accepted):

practically problem regard the high CPU usage still bending , but for the drop of the handheld traffic i found one useful work a round that to isolate the handhelds traffic in separate VLAN .